# replace value between tags in text using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace value from "4xsddfdf" to "3AAAAAA" in below file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://autocorp.com/soap/envelope">
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns2:section>something</ns2:section>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <aut:process>
    <payload>
    <ticket:ticektpro>
        <ticketName>4xsddfdf</ticketName>
    </ticket:ticektpro>
    </payload>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code is

```
const fs = require('fs');
const replacePath="3AAAAAA"
var REGEX = /<ticketName>(.+)</ticketName>/;
console.log(REGEX)
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync('query_request.txt', 'utf8');
matchresult = fileContent.match('<ticketName>4xsddfdf</ticketName>');
console.log('------------------------------match',matchresult)
fileContent = fileContent.replace(REGEX, function replacer(matchresult,replacePath) {
  // load and return the replacement file
console.log('----------------------------------',fileContent)
  return fs.readFileSync(replacePath, 'utf8');
});
console.log(fileContent)
fs.writeFileSync('query_request.txt', fileContent);
```

but the value replacement is not working. can any one help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighter is actually highlighting the problem: you are not scaping the bar in the closing tag so the regex ends there. Try with:

```
var REGEX = /<ticketName>(.+)<\/ticketName>/;
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zlXfQK/1

For the additional question in comments, there's a code that replaces the file with the new contents:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const replacePath="3AAAAAA";
const filenameIn = 'query_request.txt';
const filenameOut = 'query_request_out.txt';
var REGEX = /<ticketName>(.+)<\/ticketName>/;
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filenameIn, 'utf8');
fileContent = fileContent.replace(
    REGEX,
    '<ticketName>' + replacePath + '</ticketName>'
);
fs.writeFileSync(filenameOut, fileContent, 'utf8');
```

Just change `filenameOut` to the correct value.

After that you have a file with the contents changed that you can send or whatever you want to do.

Comment: after changed the line , i am getting below error. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '3AAAAAA'

Comment: That's another different problem. You are using `replacePath` variable, whose value is constant, as a path in `fs.readFileSync()`. What do you want to achieve? If you are trying to insert one file in another, you should generate the complete correct filename, probably from the regex.

Comment: All i need is to replace this constant variable into the file.Can you please help me to resolve the issue , in my above code

Comment: I think so but I don't know what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain?

Comment: When i run this script it will ask me the Ticketnumber (currently this is constant variable here) , then using the ticket number i am going to replace it in the file.  After that i am making some api request using this txt file and get the response

Comment: Thanks. And do you want to replace just the string `4xsddfdf` with `3AAAAAA` yielding `<ticketName>3AAAAAA</ticketName>`?

Comment: Yes that the thing i am looking for

Comment: Thanks , without creating new file is it possible to update value on same file?

Comment: Yes, just use the same variable for both or this: `const filenameOut = filenameIn`. If this solves your problem, would you be so kind as to mark the question as replied?